# Highlight / Bold text on autocomplete

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following code, and I want the word the user is typping turn into `bold` or `highlight`, any tips of how can I do that? Thanks!

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

//autocomplete
$(".auto").autocomplete({
    source: "search.php",
    minLength: 1
});                

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From bootstrap autocomplete tutorial, something like :

```
if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
      /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
      b = document.createElement("DIV");
      /*make the matching letters bold:*/
      b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
      b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
```

Where `arr` is your array to look into and `val` the text you are typing